# AB →→ C already in fourth normal form

Tags: sql, normalization, decomposition

Consider the following set of functional dependencies on the relation schema R = (A, B, C, D, E). Decompose the relation into a collection of relation schemas in 4NF. Provide detailed information of the decomposition process.

```
AB →→ C
B → D
A → E
```

If you start from the top with AB →→ C, doesn't that fit 4nf and you are done?

Comment: That sounds like a homework question.

Comment: you may also want to post this on : https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is a review question for a final, I know bcnf, but when multi-value dependencies are added I am not too sure. When you get your candidate keys {A,B} you see that AB is a super key and that AB →→ C is 4nf and there is nothing to do for the question.

Comment: @Nick you seem to be confusing a multivalued dependency for a schema.

Comment: "AB →→ C" means {A,B} multidetermines {C}. Please show your work in finding the CK(s). Please be more explict about all your reasoning.